# How to solve this integral equation, where the unknown function appears within another function.

Tags: calculus, integro-differential-equations

I'm searching for a function $\theta(\phi)$ shuch that $\theta(0)=0$, $\theta(\phi_f)=2n\pi$, and

$$
\int_0^{\phi_f} \cos(\theta(\phi)) d \phi=0,\qquad \int_0^{\phi_f} \sin(\theta(\phi)) d \phi = 1
$$
where $\phi_f$ is some angle, and $n$ is some integer value.

They are clearly integral equations, but I find Laplace's method difficult due to the composition. On the other hand I have tried to test different plausible solutions parameterizing the trajectory but condition $\theta(\phi_f)=2n\pi$ is complicated to take into account so I wanted to ask you if you have any idea how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Partial answer)

By linearity of the integral, the two integral conditions can be merged into the more simple constraint
$$
\int_0^{\phi_f} e^{i\theta(\phi)} \mathrm{d}\phi = i.
$$
If we denote by $F(\phi)$ the antiderivative of $f(\phi) = e^{i\theta(\phi)}$, this constraint translates as $F(\varphi_f) - F(0) = i$. Moreover, by definition, we have $F'(\varphi) = e^{i\theta(\phi)}$, hence the additional conditions $F'(\varphi_f) = F'(0) = 1$.

Once you have found a function $F$ sastisfying to these relations, your desired function is given by $\theta_k(\phi) = -i\ln(F'(\phi)) + 2\pi k$, $k \in \mathbb{Z}$. Note that you still need to specify the branch of the logarithm.